# Switch CSS classes with state

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state

I am currently creating with React a login/register template which mimics in functionality the [groupon login](https://www.groupon.com/login). Specifically, I am targeting the switching of the colored border when toggling between `i have an account` and `i'm a new customer`. The template is very common in today's development, and I have seen many poorly coded solutions which ignore best practices altogether.

I'll start by stating that the best solution uses `state`.
I would then create the following (incomplete, obviously):

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="login" />
  <div className="register" />
</div>
```

I then thought to give both divs a state, and a border-bottom spec to render the colored border. The issue I am seeing is how to best implement the toggle of which one is active.

Another thought experiment is to hardcode everything up to the input fields. Then, when the user clicks on the `I'M A NEW CUSTOMER` field, all I have to do is set an active state to that component, and render .

Again, the point of this question is to answer how to best implement this login/registration form. By the way, Groupon gives their showing component a class of `active`.

**EDIT**: As was pointed out by Sunny Wong, and reflective of my assumption, his solution uses state and implements with my component as follows:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: "login"
    };
  }

  handleActiveTab = name => event => {
    this.setState({ activeTab: name });
  };

  render() {
    const { activeTab } = this.state;
    let joinComponent =
      activeTab === "login" ? <LoginComponent /> : <RegisterComponent />;

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div
          onClick={this.handleActiveTab("login")}
          className={classNames("login", {
            active: activeTab === "login"
          })}
        >
          Login
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={this.handleActiveTab("register")}
          className={classNames("register", {
            active: activeTab === "register"
          })}
        >
          Register
        </div>
        {joinComponent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, the post was tagged as `too broad`, yet I targeted specific topics/questions. To summarize, they were:

> - Specifically, I am targeting the switching of the colored border when
>   toggling between i have an account and i'm a new customer.
> - answer how to best implement this login/registration form

See the [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/4q908v7wmx) for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggling the classes is the way to go here. There is no need to re-render the tabs as different components, as the content is the same. The tabs only undergo a cosmetic change. There is a library called classNames (https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames), which is extremely helpful in controlling which classes get applied in a given situation.

Something like keeping state of which link is active via an id. Then toggle an 'active' class which is responsible for applying the active styling.

```
state = { activeTab: 'login' }

handleActiveTab = e => {
  //sets state of activeTab
}

render() {
  const { activeTab } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div onClick={this.handleActiveTab} className={classNames('login', { active: activeTab === 'login' })} />
      <div onClick={this.handleActiveTab} className={classNames('register', { active: activeTab === 'register' })} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This was great, thank you for the answer. I edited the original to reflect my implementation. One question I do have is, if i don't specify `handleActiveTab = name => event => {}` with the double function, I get an infinite loop (see `handleActiveTab = name => {}`). Any idea why ?

Comment: Because you are invoking the function on your onClick handler when the component renders. The function also calls setState which causes a render, which will invoke the function again.

You did the correct thing to prevent the infinite loop but introduced what is considered an anti-pattern, as that second function is anonymous. Everytime you re-render you will create a new function, which react does not have reference to. I'm sure you can find resources by googling react-antipatterns.

I don't believe it is a bottleneck unless you are using this component to render hundreds of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div className="wrapper">
  <div className={`login ${this.state.active==CONST.LOGIN? 'active':''}`} onClick={e=>{this.setState({active:CONST.LOGIN}}/>
  <div className={`register ${this.state.active==CONST.REGISTER? 'active':''}`} onClick={e=>{this.setState({active:CONST.REGISTER}} />
</div>
```

you have to maintain state for active in active that will allow you to load right component (login/register). CONST.LOGIN and CONST.REGISTER are constants that you have to manage. you can use just 1/2 the dirty way.